# C#, WPF, API MS SQL. Как полученные данные по API, загрузить в базу данных?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, api

Стоит такая задача: Как я могу полученные данные ПО API, загрузить в базу данных MS SQL Server. Средствами Entity Framework 6?
Алгоритм получения данных по API выглядит так:

```
 private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        //public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }


        public CarViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        string url = "http://solutions2019.hakta.pro/api/getFines?participant=01";
            try
            {
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    var serializi = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServerResponse<Car>));
                    var response_object = (ServerResponse<Car>)serializi.ReadObject(stream);
                    Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>(response_object.data);
                    this.DataContext = this;
                }
                DbContextObject.db.F_Car.AddRange((IEnumerable<DbModel.F_Car>)Cars);
                await DbContextObject.db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

Я исправил код таким образом, в дебаг она видит полученные данные, то есть в методе:

```
DbContextObject.db.F_Car.AddRange((IEnumerable<DbModel.F_Car>)Cars);
```

Скрин приведёт ниже.

Но выдает ошибку:

System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[dbAPI.Models.Car]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[dbAPI.DbModel.F_Car]'.

У нас есть событие на загрузку страницы, для того чтобы получить данные по API и отобразить в ListView:

```
    <ListView Name="ListCarView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding photo}"
                                       Width="200"
                                       Height="200"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding id}"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding car_num}"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding create_date}"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding licence_num}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Как я описал модель данных:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Car
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string car_num { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string create_date { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string licence_num { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string photo { get; set; }
    }
```

Ещё раз попробую изложить проблему, я не могу понять, как мне полученные данные по API загрузить в базу данных MS SQL? С помощью выше прописанного кода, я получаю данные. Надо его дополнить, чтобы данные можно было загрузить в Базу Данных. Извините за тавтологию )

Скриншот:

[image: Метод вроде как работает, но SaveChanges() выдёт ошибки]

ХЗ, может поможет, но вот скриншот загруженной модели Базы Данных:
[image: Таблица]

И приведу код:

```
namespace dbAPI.DbModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class F_Car
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string car_num { get; set; }
        public string create_date { get; set; }
        public string licence_num { get; set; }
        public string photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Для теста, я указал тип данных nvarchar(max) в базе данных.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119222/discussion-on-question-by---c-wpf-api-ms-sql---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 разных класса модели данных `dbAPI.DbModel.F_Car‌` и `dbAPI.Models.Car`, несмотря на то что имеют одинаковый набор полей. Поэтому преобразование между ними возможно только "волоком".

```cs
DbContextObject.db.F_Car.AddRange(Cars.Select(car 
    => new DbModel.F_Car 
    {
        id = car.id,
        car_num = car.car_num,
        create_date = car.create_date,
        licence_num = car.licence_num,
        photo = car.photo
    }));
```

Но вообще советую избавиться от клона, чтобы не выполнять таких глупых преобразований.

---

Так же исправил ошибки в коде получения данных: `IDisposable` объекты надо диспозить, и в `async void` надо обязательно обрабатывать исключения, иначе вы их просто не увидите и не поймете, почему не работает.

Чтобы коллекцию Cars можно было обновлять в любой момент, а не только до назначения `DataContext`, надо реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Собственно - это единственный правильный путь, а назначение `DataContext` в методе - костыль, и сработает только один раз.

```cs
public partial class Page1 : Page, INotifyPropertChanged
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;

    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get => _cars;
        set
        {
            _cars = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://solutions2019.hakta.pro/api/getFines?participant=01";
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                var serializi = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServerResponse<Car>));
                var response_object = (ServerResponse<Car>)serializi.ReadObject(stream);
                Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>(response_object.data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // или залогируйте это
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Для того чтобы выше код получал API:

                    Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>(response_object.data);
                    this.DataContext = this;

Но мой вопрос до сих остаётся открытым.((

Comment: @ДмитрийПафос вы имеете в виду то что если не прописать явно `DataContext` прямо в методе, то на экран не выведется? Ща напишу, что сделать.

Comment: Да, то что он выше написал, не выдал данные в ListView

Comment: Но вопрос состоит не в том, чтобы отобразить данные в ListView. Я не могу понять, как эти полученные данные залить в базу данных...

Comment: @ДмитрийПафос дополнил. А я про базу данных не знаю ответа, может кто другой подскажет. Я вам правлю те ошибки, что вижу. Вон комментарий от Bulson под вопросом посмотрите.

Comment: @ДмитрийПафос с `INotifyPropertyChanged` получилось? Если не пробовали, попробуйте, штука крутая и в будущем вам пригодится.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119214/discussion-between---and-aepot).

Answer (score 1):

Пример на простую консольную прогу `.Net 5` c nuget пакетом `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleTestApp");

        //получаем данные
        string url = "http://solutions2019.hakta.pro/api/getFines?participant=01";
        var service = new WebCarsApiService(url);
        var cars = await service.GetCarsAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Получено {cars.Count()} авто");

        //сохраняем данные в БД
        var repository = new CarsRepository();
        int result = await repository.SaveCarsAsync(cars);

        Console.WriteLine($"Сохранено {result.ToString()} авто в БД");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Классы для работы с `json`

```
public class WebCar
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string car_num { get; set; }
    public string licence_num { get; set; }
    public string create_date { get; set; }
    public string photo { get; set; }
}

public class WebCars
{
    public List<WebCar> data { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}
```

Класс для работы с БД и в приложении

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarNumber { get; set; }
    public string LicenceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Класс для работы с Web API

```
public class WebCarsApiService
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    private readonly string _url;

    public WebCarsApiService(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(url));
        }

        _url = url;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetCarsAsync()
    {
        var result = new List<Car>();
        WebCars webCars = null;

        try
        {
            using (var response = await _client.GetAsync(_url))
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                webCars = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<WebCars>(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        if (webCars != null && webCars.data.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var wc in webCars.data)
            {
                var car = new Car
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(wc.id),
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Parse(wc.create_date),
                    CarNumber = wc.car_num,
                    LicenceNumber = wc.licence_num,
                    Photo = wc.photo
                };
                result.Add(car);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Класс контекста

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDataContext()
    {
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source=cars.db");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Класс репозитория

```
public class CarsRepository
{
    public async Task<int> SaveCarsAsync(IEnumerable<Car> cars)
    {
        int result = 0;
        using(var context = new AppDataContext())
        {
            context.Cars.AddRange(cars);
            result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Отработало так

[image: результат работы]

База выглядит так

[image: вид на данные в таблице БД]

Целиком пример [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/FromSiteToDb)

Comment: Оу, спасибо. Сейчас попробую сделать так же

Comment: Если что то [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/FromSiteToDb) репозиторий проекта