# C#, WPF. Как сделать так, чтобы DataContext обновлялась?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Стоит такая задача:** У меня есть ListView, где отображены данные из базы данных, вот код:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Service> Services { get; set; }

 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
       Services = new ObservableCollection<Service>(DbContextObject.db.Service);
       this.DataContext = this;
 }
```

Когда я провожу удаление выбранной записи:

```
 private void RemoveSelectedItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            try
            {
                Service SelectedService = (Service)ListService.SelectedItem;
                if (SelectedService != null)
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно хотите удалить запись?", "Подтвердите удаление.", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        DbContextObject.db.Service.Remove(SelectedService);
                        DbContextObject.db.SaveChanges();
                        Page_Loaded(null, null);
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

Запись удаляется, но данные на ListView не обновляются, вот код самой ListView:

```
 <ListView Name="ListService"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding MainImagePath}"
                                       Width="150"
                                       Height="150"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                                  Margin="20,10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Title}" ContentStringFormat="Наименование услуги: {0}" FontSize="18"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Cost}" ContentStringFormat="Стоимость: {0:C}" FontSize="14"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding DurationInSeconds, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Converter}}" FontSize="14"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Discount}" ContentStringFormat="* Скидка: {0}%" FontSize="14"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource FunctionButtonStyle}"
                                            Content="Редактировать"
                                            Click="EditSelectedItem_Click"
                                            Width="150">
                                        <Button.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Resources>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource FunctionButtonStyle}"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                            Content="Удалить"
                                            Click="RemoveSelectedItem_Click"
                                            Width="150">
                                        <Button.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Resources>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы после события удаления DataContext отобразил свежие данные из Базы Данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте свойство `SelectedService`.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Service> Services { get; set; }

public Service SelectedService { get; set; }
```

Как-то так должно получиться:

```
private void RemoveSelectedItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (SelectedService != null && MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно хотите удалить запись?", "Подтвердите удаление.", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            DbContextObject.db.Service.Remove(SelectedService);
            DbContextObject.db.SaveChanges();
            Services.Remove(SelectedService);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Уберите `Name` и добавьте привязку `SelectedItem`

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedService}">
```

Напоминаю про `INotifyPropertyChanged`, если вы вдруг захотите переприсвоить коллекцию `Services`, то вам его надо [реализовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1238704/373567).